# .NET Outlook Add-in and WCF/Inter-process communication

Tags: c#, wcf

I need a tip/advice/recommendation.

I'm finishing up a Outlook Add-in developed in C#.
I would like this add-in to communication with another application (let's call it Client.exe).

Client.exe and the add-in will always be running on the same computer. 
Client.exe is a single instance application.

What would be the easiest/most convenient way for me to allow the Add-in to communicate with the Client.exe?
Would that be WCF? 
Any good resource you can recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw. both the add-in and the client.exe are written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WCF is probably the way to go. [MS has said themselves](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k.aspx) that the older .NET Remoting is deprecated in favor of WCF. Obviously, the core docs are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k.aspx).

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k.aspx) might help with WCF for IPC in .NET 4.0. (IPC = Inter-Process Communication)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use WCF. You can host a WCF service inside of client.exe, and the add-in can call the service. You can use any transport, but in your situation could take advantage of named pipes sending binary data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both the answers.
I actually ended up not using WCF, as I realized I could do all of the interaction without even creating an add-in. 
Instead I just use the MS Outlook Interop dlls to communicate with Outlook from my Client.exe.